# How to get an item's position from item's ID in android spinner?

Tags: android

I need to get an item's position in spinner knowing it's ID. I've tried to do it with Spinner and SpinnerAdapter classes but there are no corresponding methods there.

Thanks,

Aleksander

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create the Spinner items via your SpinnerAdapter, so you determine the position of the items. If you create the Spiner items from some kind of collection, you could search that for the ID.

Comment: And what's for content provider as a data source for my adapter? ;)

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I did it last night for the first time:

```
Spinner mySpn = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
String spnItem = (String) mySpn.getItemAtPosition(mySpn.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
static final int getAdapterPositionById(final Adapter adapter, final long id) throws NoSuchElementException {
    final int count = adapter.getCount();

    for (int pos = 0; pos < count; pos++) {
        if (id == adapter.getItemId(pos)) {
            return pos;
        }    
    }

    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
```

It's generic enough to work for any adapter type that supports ids (e.g., implements `Adapter#getItemId(int position)` in a **meaningful** way)

Answer (score 4):

you can query the selected position by `Spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()`

or alternatively you will get the selected item position if you override the method `onItemSelected()`

Comment: The matter is I need to SET selected item knowing item's ID. There's no such method as setSelectedItem(long id) so I need a position

Comment: well if you are using an array adapter you know how many elements that you are going to insert, in that case you can set by calling Spinner.setselection(int position) position refers to the element in the Listadapter starting from 0.

Comment: @Vamsi And what if you use a pre-defined array of Strings in strings.xml? Technically you should NOT know which entry is in which position, otherwise there would be no point in defining those String arrays in strings.xml (and there definitely is a point to it)

Answer (score 1):

well if u use this u can get the position no of the item then u can match with ur array of values

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
system.out.println(arg2);
}
```

here arg2 is the index of the selected items position , rest i hope u can manage